# Touch ID Unavailable After Sleep MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, touch-id

I am using a 2016 MacBook Pro 15" (Model A1707). Whenever I put my computer on sleep, then wake it up, I find that I cannot use Touch ID to unlock my computer. The screenshot below shows the screen when I wake up the computer. How can I enable Touch ID after my computer is asleep? Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed in macOS 10.12.2

Comment: That does not seem to be the case.   I am on 10.12.4 and the touchId is still disabled after sleep mode.

Comment: Agreed, 10.12.5 and it's still an issue.

Comment: Sometimes the Touch ID is still disabled after sleep mode on Mac OS X 10.13.6.

Comment: Still broken on 10.14.6

Answer (score -1):

uninstall **Symantec** antivirus if you have

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score -3):

I messed with the sleep/screen saver settings and restarted and it seemed to have fixed my issue.

Comment: Could you please specify which settings you changed?